# Correct recursive python implementation of Newton 's differences interpolation method, obtaining some of the returned values inside recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a recursion function in python to evaluate the sequence of an [interpolation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences#Definition).

It's graphically explained in this image:

[image]

`f[x]=f(x)` and `f[x0,x1]= f[x1]-f[x0]) / (x1 - x0)` and so when `f[x0,x1,...xn]=f[all_leastFirst,allbutLast] / xlast-xfirst`.

This is it then, recursively.

I had got the following code:

```
xxs=[]
yys=[]
coeficientes = []
h = {}
r = 0.0

def a_j(xx,yy):
    global r
    if len(yy) == 1:
        h[xx[0]] = yy[0]
        return yy[0]
    else:
        r = (a_j(xx[1:],yy[1:])  - a_j(xx[:-1],yy[:-1])) / (xx-1]-xx[0])
        h[''.join(str(i) for i in xx[::-1])]=r
        coeficientes.append(r)
        return ( r )
```

But it was needed to get as output an array with ***only the numbers marked in a green circle***. I was lost about how to get only those in a recursive implementation. 
One common pattern about them will be they ALWAYS start at ***`X_0`***, so I opted about tagging them or using a dictionary might help.

Expected result would be:

```
[1,1.71828,1.47625,.84553]
```

I was obtaining:

```
[1, 2.71828, 7.3890599999999997, 20.085540000000002, 1.71828, 4.6707799999999997, 12.696480000000001, 1.4762499999999998, 4.0128500000000003, 0.84553333333333347]
```

**For another run** wit different parameters, if it's called by:

```
a_j([1,2,3,5][4,3.5,4,5.6])
```

Should output:

```
[4,-0.5,0.5,-0.1]
```

I was obtaining:

```
[4, 3.5, 4, 5.6, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7999999999999998, 0.09999999999999994, -0.10000000000000002]
```

**Another example:**

```
a_j([-2,-1,0,1,2], [13,24,39,65,106])
```

Will output:

```
[13, 24, 39, 65, 106, 11, 15, 2, 26, 5, 1, 41, 7, 0, -1]
```

But the output should be:

```
[13,11,2,1.167,-0.125]
```

I also managed to code this **iterative implementation**, which is **already correct**:

```
diferencias = {}
coeficientes = []

def sublists_n(l, n):
    subs = []
    for i in range(len(l)-n+1):
        subs.extend([l[i:i+n]])
    return subs

def sublists(l):
    subs = []
    for i in range(len(l)-1,0,-1):
        subs.extend(sublists_n(l,i))
    subs.insert(0,l)
    return subs[::-1]


def diferenciasDivididas(xx,yy,x):

    combinaciones = sublists([i for i in range(len(xx))])

    for c in combinaciones:

        if len(c) == 1:
            diferencias[str(c[0])]= float(yy[c[0]])
            if c[0] == 0:
                coeficientes.append(float(yy[c[0]]))

        else:
            c1 = diferencias.get(''.join(str(i) for i in c[1:]))
            c2 = diferencias.get(''.join(str(i) for i in c[:-1]))

            d = float(( c1 - c2 ) / ( xx[c[len(c)-1]] - xx[c[0]] ))

            diferencias[''.join(str(i) for i in c)] = d

            if c[0] == 0:
                coeficientes.append(float(d))
```

**I only wonder what was I missing?**

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Can you please explain how is `f[x0, x1] = 1.71828`? As per your formula, it should have been  much lesser value.

Comment: @thefourtheye As that's `f(x1)-f(x0)/(x1-x0)` that's `2.71828-1/(1-0)`

Comment: I managed to get the second column right and I don't understand the third column now :(

Comment: I got `[1.71828, 4.67078, 12.696480000000001]`, but the next column I got is `[2.9524999999999997, 8.0257]`

Comment: Are you sure about the correctness of the second output?  [13,11,4,7,-3] ? or is it [13, 11, 2, 1, -1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the script a bit.

```
    array=[]
    r='s'
    s=0
    def a_j(xx,yy):
        global r,s
        if r == 's':
            s=xx[0]
            r=0.0
        if len(yy) == 1:
            if xx[0]==s: array.append(yy[0])
            return float(yy[0])

        else:
            r=( a_j(xx[1:],yy[1:])  - a_j(xx[:-1],yy[:-1])) / (xx[-1]-xx[0])
            if xx[0]==s: array.append(r)
            return float(r)

    a_j([1,2,3,5],[4,3.5,4,5.6])
    print array
```

Output:
[4, -0.5, 0.5, -0.10000000000000002]

also, the second example that you have given doesnt look correct.
a_j([-2,-1,0,1,2], [13,24,39,65,106]) --> [13,11,4,7,-3]

above answer says that the 3rd element is 4.

```
    3rd element means --> x(-2,-1,0) -> x(-1,0)  -  x(-2,-1)/(2)
                                     -> x(0)-x(-1)/1  -  x(-1)-x(-2)/(1) /(2)
                                     ->(39-24) - (24-13)   /(2)
                                     ->15-11/(2)
                                     ->4/2 =2
```

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, 3rd example was just wrong, my apologies. I would *only* add to cast to float the return values to get right results. I actually don't know why they just can't work as it, because they happen to be integers first?

You're eager SO needs, thanks!

Comment: Also, why exactly should `r` and `s` `global`?

Comment: Could you give an eye to my edit and give opinion on my iterative implementation. And finally, what was I missing in my recursive implementation? (I think that wrong example fooled my and confused me)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You are correct.
  r and s are global because we need to check the value of these variables in and only in the first iteration. Couldnt find any better solution. 
Your code was looking good. I think that example confused you.

Comment: Well I think it happens. So What difference makes if those variables are not global?

Comment: i made it global since we need the initial values inside the function only once. If it was a local variable, it will assign the value to the variables every time the function is called. Which will satisfy the first conditional statement always. We need to fetch the first element of the original elements passed to the function. It can be done only during the first iteration of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting negative values here because you have not enclosed the subtraction in parenthesis.Otherwise the code looks good.

```
   r = ( a_j(xx1,yy1)  - a_j(xx0,yy0)  ) / (xx[len(xx)-1]-xx[0])
```

http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

Comment: That helps a bit, but it's not exactly my error. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    array=[]
    h={}
    r=0

    def a_j(xx,yy):
        global r
        if len(yy) == 1:
            h[int(xx[0])]=yy[0]
            return yy[0]

        else:
            r=( a_j(xx[1:],yy[1:])  - a_j(xx[:-1],yy[:-1])) / (xx[-1]-xx[0])
            h[int(''.join(str(i) for i in xx[::-1]))]=r
            return r

    a_j([0,1,2,3], [1,2.71828,7.38906,20.08554])
    array=[h[key] for key in  sorted(h.keys())]
    print array
```

Output:
[1, 2.71828, 7.3890599999999997, 20.085540000000002, 1.71828, 4.6707799999999997, 12.696480000000001, 1.4762499999999998, 4.0128500000000003, 0.84553333333333347]

In this code, the values are first assigned to a dict with keys as the elements of xx reversed and converted to an integer.

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer really helped me. I just realized I actually need to get *only some* of the values calculated, I edited my question, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing recursion, you will append each value as it exits the function, you will wind up getting the appending done in reverse  xn, ... , x3, x2, x1

Once you finish the total recursion and exit for the last time, just reverse the list, which is relatively simple by several methods and has been asked before.  I leave the method you want to use up to you (or remember "Google is your friend")