# How to obtain the original indexes from a sliced list in python?

Tags: python, list

When I have a list, let's say:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And I do:

```
l[1:] #Obtain
[2,3,4,5]
```

or

```
l[:-1] # Obtain
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But is there any way to obtain original indexes from the original list before slicing, no matter the length of the list manipulated?

In other words, when I get a sublist, I'd like to get what indexes do their elements belong compared to original list.

Comment: Your question doesn't parse as valid English. Could you rephrase it into something more understandable? Perhaps provide example output you'd like to get.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your last sentence makes absolutely no sense. What are you trying to do again?

Comment: If the question is "does the sliced list know its own indices in the original", then the answer is no.

Comment: Furthermore, if @larsmans is interpreting this correctly, what is the use case? If you are slicing a list, surely you know the indices you are slicing in advance? Why would you need to determine them dynamically?

Comment: You can replace items at unwanted indices by None and check if it's None every time. Otherwise there is no way to preserve indices since that is a brand new list after slicing.

Comment: You present a question to obtain a loony behavior without giving the slightest explanation why you need such a weird data structure. There's certainly a way to construct such a data structure as an instance of a class which would be build with a bunch of weird methods. But that would be possible if we would know all the behaviors awaited for such instances. For example, what if a new-new list is created from a new list resulting of a first slicing ? Must the behavior be the same if element are randomely added or deleted inside the list ? To be short: why do you want such a structure ?

Comment: @eyquem, It helped me solve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341426/correct-recursive-python-implementation-of-interpolation-method-obtaining-some) iteratively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> def printy(v):
...     for x, y in v:
...         print('Original index:', x, ', original element:', y)
... 
>>> # Original list
... a = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 0]
>>> with_original_indexes = tuple(zip(range(len(a)), a)) # or list()
>>> with_original_indexes = tuple(enumerate(a)) # Equivalent to the above
>>> printy(with_original_indexes)
Original index: 0 , original element: 1
Original index: 1 , original element: 2
Original index: 2 , original element: 2
Original index: 3 , original element: 4
Original index: 4 , original element: 4
Original index: 5 , original element: 4
Original index: 6 , original element: 5
Original index: 7 , original element: 0
>>> printy(with_original_indexes[1:5])
Original index: 1 , original element: 2
Original index: 2 , original element: 2
Original index: 3 , original element: 4
Original index: 4 , original element: 4
>>> printy(with_original_indexes[1:5][2:5])
Original index: 3 , original element: 4
Original index: 4 , original element: 4
>>>
```

Comment: Hey, let's say I want to get, from `[1,2,3,4,5]` a new list `[2,3,4,5]` and `[1,2,3,4]` from each of those get then `[3,4,5]`, `[2,3,4]`, `[2,3,4]` and `[1,2,3]` ... So on until getting one element lists: [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]?

Comment: In your example, what happens where there are repeated elements?

Comment: All elements are kept on their original positions and repeated elements are not removed. See the documentation on zip function (http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: `zip(range(len(a)), a)` is idiomatically written `enumerate(a)`.

Answer (score 2):

For each of the slice notations you gave there is a more explicit equivalent:

```
l[1:] == l[1:len(l)]
l[:-1] == l[0:len(l)-1]
```

To get the list of indexes you can feed those numbers into `range`:

```
range(1, len(l))
range(0, len(l)-1)
```

Comment: Why `:len(l)` won't be out of range?

Comment: @diegoaguilar because slices do *not* include the ending index, just like `range`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking, but if you have the sequence and want to know it's original indices, and ff you can assume that the sequence is unique, you can [use a list comprehension to find the sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459493/find-indexes-of-sequence-in-list-in-python):

```
[(i, i+len(l)) for i in xrange(len(a)) if a[i:i+len(l)] == l]
```